# Working with dataframes in a list: Rename variables

Tags: list, r, data-manipulation, data-management

Define:

```
dats <- list( df1 = data.frame(A=sample(1:3), B = sample(11:13)),
        df2 = data.frame(AA=sample(1:3), BB = sample(11:13)))
```

s.t.

```
> dats
$df1
  A  B
1 2 12
2 3 11
3 1 13

$df2
  AA BB
1  1 13
2  2 12
3  3 11
```

I would like to change all variable names from all caps to lower.  I can do this with a loop but somehow cannot get this `lapply` call to work:

```
dats <- lapply(dats, function(x) 
            names(x)<-tolower(names(x)))
```

which results in:

```
> dats
$df1
[1] "a" "b"

$df2
[1] "aa" "bb"
```

while the desired result is:

```
> dats
$df1
  a  b
1 2 12
2 3 11
3 1 13

$df2
  aa bb
1  1 13
2  2 12
3  3 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use `return` at the end of a function, the last evaluated expression returned.  So you need to return `x`.

```
dats <- lapply(dats, function(x) {
            names(x)<-tolower(names(x))
            x})
```

Comment: Many thanks.  I was missing the braces but why the need to return x?  Hard to make sense of "If you don't use `return` at the end of a function, the last evaluated expression returned"

Comment: The braces were unnecessary in your example; I had to add them because I had more than one line.  The "last evaluated expression" in your function is `names(x) <- tolower(names(x))`.  The results of that assignment are `"a" "b"` and `"aa" "bb"`, respectively, so that's what the function returns.  For example, try `(names(x) <- tolower(names(x)))`.

Comment: Ok, checked the help file (?function does not work, ?'function' does) and now understand.  This example makes it clear `function(x,y){ z <- x^2 + y^2; return(x+y+z) }`: the return value differs from that evaluated in the expression, which adds more freedom.  In my case the desired return value is the data frame and not the vector `names(x)`.

Comment: Glad you understand despite my lack of clarity.  And you don't have to use `return` explicitly.  `function(x,y){ z <- x^2 + y^2; x+y+z }` does the same thing.  By the way, `?function` does not work because `function` is a reserved word.

Comment: Thanks, I added the `return` to make it explicit for those like me who are new.  The example is from the help page.